# Powershell Time Picker

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a date/time picker through Windows Forms in Powershell and am having an issue getting the time to work properly.

My goal is to try to round the current time to the nearest 15 minute interval (example: 8:43am to 8:45am) and then add 15 minute intervals to a set time, say 4:30pm. Have those outputted into a picker that people can choose. I have looked at the rounding pieces and I have only seen people who round up and down where I want to round up only:

```
$FifteenMinutes = (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 15 ).Ticks
$Date = Get-Date
$Ticks = ([Math]::Round($Date.Ticks / $FifteenMinutes, 0) * $FifteenMinutes) -as [long]
[DateTime]$Ticks
```

Here is my code:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

# Main Form
$mainForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Consolas", 13)
$mainForm.Text = "Pick Time Frame"
$mainForm.Font = $font
#$mainForm.ForeColor = "White"
#$mainForm.BackColor = "DarkOliveGreen"
$mainForm.Width = 300
$mainForm.Height = 200

# DatePicker Label
$datePickerLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$datePickerLabel.Text = "Date"
$datePickerLabel.Location = "15, 10"
$datePickerLabel.Height = 22
$datePickerLabel.Width = 90
$mainForm.Controls.Add($datePickerLabel)

# TimePicker Label
$TimePickerLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$TimePickerLabel.Text = "Time"
$TimePickerLabel.Location = "15, 45"
$TimePickerLabel.Height = 22
$TimePickerLabel.Width = 90
$mainForm.Controls.Add($TimePickerLabel)

# DatePicker
$datePicker = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker
$datePicker.Location = "110, 7"
$datePicker.Width = "150"
$datePicker.Format = [windows.forms.datetimepickerFormat]::custom
$datePicker.CustomFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
$datepicker.MinDate = Get-Date
$datepicker.MaxDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(2)
$mainForm.Controls.Add($datePicker)

# TimePicker
$TimePicker = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker
$TimePicker.Location = "110, 42"
$TimePicker.Width = "150"
$TimePicker.Format = [windows.forms.datetimepickerFormat]::custom
$TimePicker.CustomFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
$TimePicker.ShowUpDown = $TRUE
$mainForm.Controls.Add($TimePicker)

# OD Button
$okButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$okButton.Location = "15, 130"
$okButton.ForeColor = "Black"
$okButton.BackColor = "White"
$okButton.Text = "OK"
$okButton.add_Click({$mainForm.close()})
$mainForm.Controls.Add($okButton)

[void] $mainForm.ShowDialog()
$datepicker.text
$TimePicker.text
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **[`[Math]::Ceiling()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Math.Ceiling)** instead of [`[Math]::Round()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Math.Round) to always round *up*:

```
$FifteenMinutes = (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 15).Ticks
$Date = Get-Date
[long] $Ticks = ([Math]::Ceiling($Date.Ticks / $FifteenMinutes) * $FifteenMinutes)
# See caveat in bottom section.
[DateTime] $Ticks
```

To get a list of additional, future times spaced fifteen minutes apart up to and including a given end time, simply use `+` to iteratively add the interval time span; e.g.:

```
# Interval, as a [timespan] instance
$15Minutes = [timespan] '0:15' # Alternative to: New-TimeSpan -Minutes 15

# Start time, based on now (streamlined version of the above).
$rawStartTime = Get-Date
$startTime = [datetime]::new(
  [long] [Math]::Ceiling($rawStartTime.Ticks / $15Minutes.Ticks) * $15Minutes.Ticks,
  $rawStartTime.Kind
)

# Sample end time.
# To end on a fixed hour of the day, use something like (for 8 PM):
#   Get-Date $startTime -Hour 20 -Minute 0 -Second 0
$endTime = $startTime.AddHours(2)

# Create an array of time-of-day strings in 15-minute intervals 
# between the start and end time, inclusively:
[string[]] $timeStrings = 
  while ($startTime -le $endTime) {
    $startTime.ToString('HH:mm:ss') # format and output
    $startTime += $15Minutes
  }
```

---

Note: using a [`[datetime]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime) *cast* (`[DateTime] $Ticks`) yields an *unspecified* instance, i.e. one whose `.Kind` property value is `Unspecified`, which means that it is unspecified whether the instance represents a *local* or a *UTC* point in time.

To make sure that the input `.Kind` is preserved, call the relevant `[datetime]` *constructor*:

```
[datetime]::new($Ticks, $Date.Kind)
```